# ScrollTop on page load issue

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have a question about a scrollTop function i've added in my website to scroll down to a certain division called "test" on the moment the page loads. i use the scrollTop function and it works for a moment, but then it scrolls back to the top of the website. i already tried to add preventdefault and return false, but both solutions didn't work. this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(document).scrollTop($("#test").offset().top);

    });
    //some other code
});
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddlet that demonstrates the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#test').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/)

---

- Right now you are having nested `$( document ).ready( handler )` inside your code causing the issue.
- Actually, `$( document ).ready(function() {..}` is equivalent to calling `$(function() {..}`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a document ready inside your document ready. I can tweak your code to be a little stronger, but it may not fix the issue. It sounds like you could have a conflicting script which is moving it up to the top, but try changing your current code to:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTop($("#test").offset().top);
});
```

Comment: i tried both of the suggestions and removed the other jquery code i had. but still the same issue.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the issue? Or a link to the website?

Comment: if i create the situation in jsfiddle it works fine. i cant show the website because i'm developing on a local server.

Comment: found out the script works fine in firefox. but not in chrome. didn't found the solution though. anybody any idea how this problem can be related to chrome.

Comment: We can't debug your issue without being able to replicate it or seeing any code. It could be a million things. Maybe you should put a copy online.